# Asp.net is not supporting dll files of Biometrics Attendence Machine's SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ZK Teco Bio-metrics Attendance device. I need to integrate this device with my Asp.net project, so my team can remotely access the machine to check their attendance records. I have downloaded [Official SDK](http://www.zkteco.eu/index.php/downloads/software-downloads) and add references in my project and have gone through with the [registry process](http://www.zkteco.eu/index.php/faq-category/sdk/registering-sdk) to make device connection but I can't make the connection and getting this error:

**"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 800700c1  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)."**

However, I have successfully connected the device with my C# Windows Form project (Desktop Application) and can use all functionalities of the same SDK.

What should I do to connect the device with my Asp.net project?

Comment: did you enable 32-bit in IIS?

Comment: no how can I do this? @DanielA.White

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reason for this error.

**First reason**

The ZK Techo SDK dlls are not registered under your windows 32 bit directory

**Solution**:

TO register the ZK dll under windows 32 bit directory

**Step 1**

Download the latest version of ZK SDK from the ZKTeco website

**Step 2**

Extract the downloaded folder and open it.
It contains “SDK-Ver*\32bit\” folder open it and copy all the file under 32 bit folder
*is the available version number

**Step 3**

Paste all the copied files under windows 32 bit directory folder 
The most common path of windows 32 directory folder is
“C:\Windows\System32\”

**Step 4 (Register ZK 32 bit SDK)**

The files you Just copied and pasted into windows 32 bit directory folder contains a file name “Register_SDK_x86.bat” run it as Administrator and wait until the ZK SDK dll are registered it usually take 2 -3 minutes.

**Second Reason**

Change the **target platform** of your Web Application from **Any CPU** to **x86**.

Right click on your project name in visual studio solution explorer go to
 **properties -> Build ->** under general you can find Platform target change it to Any CPU to x86.
Build your web application and publish it.
Hopefully your problem shall be solved.